# How to make the Heading of collapsible item at the center in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/Z78Gz/

In this the heading("Summary") is at the left… Even if i try aligning it at the center it comes at the left…. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to align the "Summary" text, you have to use this css style :

```
h2 .ui-btn-inner {
    text-align: center;
}
```